# fopen, get_file_contents, alternative for cache purpose?

Tags: php, caching, fopen

Im currently trying to figure out, how i can rebuild cache on my site.

I have a cache plugin, that works perfect, but i need to get my cron script to "simulate" a real request to rebuild the cache (it does not have this function).

I have a while loop that get's all the URL's, and with fopen AND get_file_contents, i have been able to generate a cache, BUT it do not have everything (can't be used as a cache).

So basically, I need to use a function/method that "actually loads the URL", but can be used as a cron script.

Can someone help me out here? Do i need to make a HTTP-Request instead, ect. I'm lost.

**Note**: If i open the website with my browser, the cache is generated and are correct.

With fopen or get_file_contents, it check's the site, but does not generate a valid cache! :-)

Could something like this work:

```
    <?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.mywebsite.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch)
echo $data; // Dont echo, it's a cron script
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ob_` methods to cache when your pages are accessed rather than having to crawl them.  Some Pseudo-code (just the if-conditions are pseudo):

```
$cached_file_path = 'some path for cached file';
//TODO: would use filemtime($cached_file_path) and time() to determine if file was
//cached today. could also do it every 3 hours, or whatever
If file has not been cached today or cachefile does not exist, then
{
    ob_start(); // starts recording the output in a buffer
    //TODO: do all your database reads and echos
    .....
    $contents = ob_get_contents(); // gets all the output for you to save
    //TODO: save contents to file at $cached_file_path
   ....
   ob_end_flush(); // returns the content to client
   //means we can cache the file and send to client at same time
   //so this doesn't have to be run separately
   exit;
}
else
{
    //cache is current, so just serve the cached file
    include($cached_file_path);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it already does that. But the system is to slow (prestashop) and I can't have visitors caching the site when visiting (5-10 seconds). I need somehow to cache/rebuild cache, like every sunday night. Thanks for the suggestion. Is there any other way to "simulate" a visit?

Comment: @user3502108, So you could give it a request param that causes it to cache, and then just have a cronjob that hits the pages with that param, and it will cache.

Comment: I'm not advanced user, but the fopen actually "loads the site" like a real visit (i suppose), but just need a param to "get it all cached". I have tried to read all documentation on fopen. Hmm.. Can you point me out in the right direction? Is my question impossible, without a "real visitor"? :-)

Comment: Just a note: It caches the site with fopen, but the cache that it serves, are still like 5-10 seconds. Like it haven't cached at all.

Comment: @user3502108, That's why I'm using `include` rather than `fopen` when I just read the cached file. Use `fopen` and `fwrite` when saving it, of course, but not when reading it.

Comment: Oh, I didnt see that. When im home, i will try your code and see if it works. The include, does it work with a http url? My cron script is on a different server, then the actual site

Comment: @user3502108, If you're saving your cache on a different server than the webserver, its definitely going to be slow.

Comment: No, im just running my script on a different server ;) But esentially i need to call the website, with my script. The website then generates the cache (cache plugin is installed) :-) Can't i simulate somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried different approaches..

Well, if it put the direct link into my cron job manager, it does refresh the cache.

There must be somehow, i can make my script emulate that behavior?